# Performance/Load testing subversion

Tags: svn, load-testing

I'm about to switch storage solution for a apache based subversion server and in order to compare the performance between the two solutions I need to measure the performance in a repeatable way.

Are there any performance test tools out there that are capable of performance testing a subversion installation?

The only one I've found googling was http://sourceforge.net/projects/mstone/ but since it's for unix and I need to do this on Windows clients I'm reluctant to use it.

Comment: Where is the repository located? Local hard drive or san storage etc. ?

Comment: we are going from san to nas for reliability reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple test you could try is to [dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) and [load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) your repository with each storage solution. You don't need to test the Apache front end since you're interested in comparing storage solutions. A dump and load should exercise Subversion enough to measure if there's a significant difference between solutions. You'd just need to time something like this:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repository > /tmp/svn.dump
svnadmin create /path/to/test
svnadmin load < /tmp/svn.dump
```

Another option is to test the raw disk performance, see [Measuring Disk Performance using bonnie++](http://www.hps.com/~tpg/notebook/bonnie.php).

Comment: Simply brilliant. Thanks. A pity I didn't think of it myself ;-) Thanks!

Comment: it is a good idea to separate out the storage from the apache part. However, If the NAS is accessed over the same NIC that the apache svn listens on, well...

Answer (score 4):

I recently found collabnet's [benchmark too](https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/projects/csvn)l they use for comparing different versions of subversion. I'm using that now to get some end-to-end performance figures.